# How show data from hive using JSP and Tomcat7

Tags: hadoop, tomcat7

I am testing a JSP (JavaServer Pages) application using Tomcat7. 
The example used is "malaga_plagues". 
The app shows data from table "malaga_plagues" in Hive `(select * from malaga_plagues limit 20)`. The problem comes when I'm trying to use the table that has been created automatically with cygnus-cosmos I'm having several problems. When I try show data from my table, it doesn't work. You can check my table in Hive (select * from cristina_albaladejo_def_serv_def_servpath_sensorreading2_sensorreading_co                                                            lumn; )

I get the following exception when trying to access the function via web:

http://IP:8080/AMS_Widhoc/CommandsMgr?cmd=getTable

```
Jun 25, 2015 4:57:34 PM es.ejhz.servlets.CommandsMgr getTable
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from shark.execution.SparkTask
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:194)
    at es.ejhz.servlets.CommandsMgr.getTable(CommandsMgr.java:129)
    at es.ejhz.servlets.CommandsMgr.doGet(CommandsMgr.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

The exception ocurred when executing the query, in this part of the malaga plagues code, before formatting to JSON:

```
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from cristina_albaladejo_s_p_sample1_sample_column limit 20");
```

The table looks like this:

```
[cristina.albaladejo@cosmosmaster-gi ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cristina.albaladejo/def_serv/def_servpath/sensorreading2_sensorreading/sensorreading2_sensorreading.txt
{"recvTime":"2015-06-08T10:59:24.292","nodeid":"1", "nodeid_md":[],"sensorid":"1", "sensorid_md":[],"systemid":"1", "systemid_md":[],"value":"-25.6", "value_md":[]}
{"recvTime":"2015-06-08T11:49:20.926","nodeid":"1", "nodeid_md":[],"sensorid":"1", "sensorid_md":[],"systemid":"1", "systemid_md":[],"value":"-35.6", "value_md":[]}
{"recvTime":"2015-06-08T11:54:03.784","nodeid":"1", "nodeid_md":[],"sensorid":"1", "sensorid_md":[],"systemid":"1", "systemid_md":[],"value":"-40.4", "value_md":[]}
{"recvTime":"2015-06-08T11:54:16.064","nodeid":"1", "nodeid_md":[],"sensorid":"1", "sensorid_md":[],"systemid":"1", "systemid_md":[],"value":"-45.4", "value_md":[]}
[cristina.albaladejo@cosmosmaster-gi ~]$ hive
hive> show tables like "cristina_albaladejo*";                                                      
cristina_albaladejo_def_serv_def_servpath_sensorreading2_sensorreading_column
Time taken: 3.614 seconds
hive> select * from cristina_albaladejo_def_serv_def_servpath_sensorreading2_sensorreading_column;                                                                                        OK
2015-06-08T10:59:24.292 1       []      1       []      1       []      -25.6   []
2015-06-08T11:49:20.926 1       []      1       []      1       []      -35.6   []
2015-06-08T11:54:03.784 1       []      1       []      1       []      -40.4   []
2015-06-08T11:54:16.064 1       []      1       []      1       []      -45.4   []
Time taken: 0.726 seconds
hive> describe cristina_albaladejo_def_serv_def_servpath_sensorreading2_sensorreading_column;OK
recvtime        string  from deserializer
nodeid  string  from deserializer
nodeid_md       array<string>   from deserializer
sensorid        string  from deserializer
sensorid_md     array<string>   from deserializer
systemid        string  from deserializer
systemid_md     array<string>   from deserializer
value   string  from deserializer
value_md        array<string>   from deserializer
Time taken: 0.084 seconds
hive>
```

Comment: can you show us the relevant parts of the "malaga-plagues" code you think you are having problems/you have modified?

Comment: I have done that. I hope you can hive me answer soon.

Comment: I would need more details regarding your code, have you uploaded it to some software version control such as GitHub? The keypoint is we have another repo, https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/tree/master/resources/hive-basic-client, that mimics in a remote way the Hive CLI using Hive JDBC as well, and the query that is failing for you works perfectly for me.